# Peer-To-Peer chat iOS Application

Tags: ios

Is it possible to create a chat application that works with Peer-To-Peer, so without a server connecting the devices?

I think this would be more trustworthy for users...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but you will still need some type of server or middleman that everyone connects to at first in order to find the people to chat and distribute their ips to each client, but from that point onward you can use tcp to connect the devices without a middleman.

Comment: Thanks, to you have any links for further explanation?

Comment: @Ummsekatze [This looks like a good place to start.](http://glennsayers.com/peer-to-peer/) [Here is another link too.](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/)